# How to check prefix of string inside an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

advertisementData contains:

```
Advertisement data {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "Ali \n";
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "43200-B827-EB74-0E24-192168001107"
    );
}    
if(advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] hasPrefix:@"432"){
    NSLog("It contains this string");
    }
```

When i execute the code it gives me error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CBUUID hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170034260'.

Comment: Better use `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` instead of `@"kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"`? Else, the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" is classic, and from the rest of the message, it means that `advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]` is a `CBUUID` object, not a `NSString` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs is a `CBUUID`. Use `uuidString` to get the string.